# React callback click event `this` undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, arrow-functions

I am using d3 and react to create charts. Clicking a button will update the chart. In the component for the chart is an onclick event listener, however the "this" keeps getting mixed up

One method with arrow functions returns `Uncaught TypeError: node.getAttribute is not a function`:

```
 this.setupButtons= function() {
          d3.select('#toolbar')
            .selectAll('.buttons')
            .on('click',  ()=> {
              d3.selectAll('.buttons').classed('active', false);
              var button = d3.select(this);

              button.classed('active', true);

              var buttonId = button.attr('id');

                this.toggleDisplay(buttonId)
            });
        }
*/
```

This is of course because the `this` refers to the component instance. So I researched how to refer to the click event and found that using `e` or `event.target` is supposed to solve the issue. In react, however, an error is returned: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`

```
 this.setupButtons= function() {
              d3.select('#toolbar')
                .selectAll('.buttons')
                .on('click',  (e)=> {
                  d3.selectAll('.buttons').classed('active', false);
                  var button = d3.select(e.target);

                  button.classed('active', true);

                  var buttonId = button.attr('id');


                    this.toggleDisplay(buttonId)
                });
            }
```

Both `this.setupButtons` and `this.toggleDisplay()` are defined in the same method, which belongs to a component.

EDIT: This question does not appear to be a "duplicate" of the question provided.This was an issue of D3's handling of `event`, not the use of `this`, apparently. The solution to this question (add `d3.event.target` instead of `event.target`) is not provided as an answer in the question this supposedly duplicates.

Comment: Just use a regular function instead of an arrow function. jQuery can't provide a thisArg to arrow functions since arrow functions don't have their own `this`.

Comment: I need to refer to the the click event in `var button = d3.select(e.target);` Then I need to call `this.toggleDisplay(buttonId)` which is another function that uses the component's `this`

Comment: `e.target` should work. I don't really understand why `e` would ever be `undefined` there. I don't know React though.

Comment: `d3` goes about things a bit differently. The event is accessed from `d3` itself (`d3.event`).
https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/17/d3-js-mouse-events-and-transitions-tutorial/#how-to-use-d3-event-object

To be honest, I'm not sure how this translates into helping you in this case, but at least you won't be debugging what is normally expected of a regular `Event`.

Comment: @Ezra, can you make this an official answer? This seems to work for me. Thank you. Though I don't know what you mean by ` To be honest, I'm not sure how this translates into helping you in this case`

Answer (score 0):

You can store the reference of the outer this into another variable. I generally store it into a variable like `var that = this` and then you can reference the variable `that` wherever required.

```
this.setupButtons= function() {
          var that = this;
          d3.select('#toolbar')
            .selectAll('.buttons')
            .on('click',  ()=> {
              d3.selectAll('.buttons').classed('active', false);
              var button = d3.select(that);

              button.classed('active', true);

              var buttonId = button.attr('id');

                that.toggleDisplay(buttonId)
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`d3` goes about things a bit differently. The event is accessed from `d3` itself (`d3.event`).

Source: https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/17/d3-js-mouse-events-and-transitions-tutorial/#how-to-use-d3-event-object

Answer (score -1):

Assign `var that = this` in the outer function. Now you have a way to reference the outer `this`.

```
this.setupButtons = function () {
    var that = this;
    d3.select('#toolbar')
        .selectAll('.buttons')
        .on('click', function() {
            d3.selectAll('.buttons').classed('active', false);
            var button = d3.select(this);

            button.classed('active', true);

            var buttonId = button.attr('id');

            that.toggleDisplay(buttonId)
        });
}
```